# How can I evaluate something in Emacs init.el file?

Tags: emacs, clojure, elisp, emacs24

Every time I open .clj file, I have to run

```
M-x cider-jack-in
```

to enable Clojure auto-completion in code file.

Can I make Emacs automatically run the command when it starts?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the specific issue, however, Emacs uses mode-hooks as a primary means of activating features when a certain mode is enabled.  For example, if a file with an extension of `.clj` is defined by the `auto-mode-alist` to trigger a major-mode named `xyz-mode`, then that major-mode has a hook called `xyz-mode-hook`; and, your function can be attached to that hook -- e.g., `(add-hook 'xyz-mode-hook 'cider-jack-in)`.  NOTE:  `add-hook` has two optional arguments -- append and buffer-local.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
(require 'cider)
(defun maybe-cider-jack-in ()
  (unless (ignore-errors
            (nrepl-current-connection-buffer))
    (cider-jack-in)))

(add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook 'maybe-cider-jack-in)
```

Comment: This seems overtly complex. Can you explain what it does and in what situations this would be preferrable to simply adding an entry for `.clj` files to `auto-mode-alist` in your `.emacs` file?

Comment: It's actually a very simple code. It will call `cider-jack-in` unless there's already a cider running. `auto-mode-alist` is just for calling `clojure-mode`, it's not for this type of stuff.